# Get data from select2 and pass it to controller in yii2

Tags: yii2

I've one select2 form field, two datepickers and a search button in productnames index file. It is only to search data I'm unable to get the data selected in the select2 widget and pass it to controller which in turn can search other models.

index.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use frontend\modules\sbbtdtproduct\models\Productnames;
use yii\helpers\Json;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\sbbtdtproduct\models\ProductnamesSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Productnames';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="productnames-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-lg-5" >
                <?php
                    echo Select2::widget([
                    'model' => $model,
                    'attribute' => 'productnames_productname',
                    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Productnames::find()->all(),'productnames_productname','productnames_productname'),
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Product'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'allowClear' => true
                    ],
                    //'productname' => $productname,
                    ]);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <?= DatePicker::widget([
                    'name' => 'Start Date',
                    'attribute' => 'from_date',
                    'value' => '2014-01-31',
                    'template' => '{addon}{input}',
                        'clientOptions' => [
                            'autoclose' => true,
                            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                        ]
                ]);?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <?= DatePicker::widget([
                    'name' => 'End Date',
                    'attribute' => 'to_date',
                    'value' => '2014-01-31',
                    'template' => '{addon}{input}',
                        'clientOptions' => [
                            'autoclose' => true,
                            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                        ]
                ]);?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1" >

                <?= Html::a('Search', ['/sbbtdtproduct/production/index','productname' => $model['productnames_productname']], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

production controller action

```
public function actionIndex($productname)
    {
        $productname = yii::$app->request->get('productnames_productname');
        $searchModel = new ProductionSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $productname);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

productionsearch model

```
public function search($params,$productname)
    {
        $query = Production::find()
                ->where(['productname' => $productname]);

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'productionid' => $this->productionid,
            'productiondate' => $this->productiondate,
            'itemid' => $this->itemid,
            'prodqty' => $this->prodqty,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'productname', $this->productname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'batchno', $this->batchno]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

error - 
[image]
**update -** 
[image]
**Database Log**
[image]
The data base Log shows that no value has been passed from search model.

I can see the value selected in select2 or datepicker as below, but it's not passing to the controller.

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you checked what is the output of `$productname = yii::$app->request->get('productnames_productname');`
`

Comment: No sir.How to do that?

Comment: inside your controller action do ` var_dump(yii::$app->request->get('productnames_productname')); exit();` and check what is the output

Comment: Added var_dump(yii::$app->request->get('productnames_productname')‌​); exit(); just after $productname = yii::$app->request->get('productnames_productname');. got - syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING)

Comment: Why is this syntax error in the var_dump? am I writing it right?

Answer (score 1):

**1.on your view page**
You have not added `form` tag, so other parameters will not get posted, you must add everything inside `form` tag and `submit` that form, as follows

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use frontend\modules\sbbtdtproduct\models\Productnames;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\sbbtdtproduct\models\ProductnamesSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Productnames';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="productnames-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); 
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'action' => ['/sbbtdtproduct/production/index'],
                'method' => 'post',
                'options' => ['data-pjax' => true],
                'enableClientValidation' => FALSE
    ]);
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-lg-5" >
                <?php
                    echo Select2::widget([
                    'model' => $model,
                    'attribute' => 'productnames_productname',
                    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Productnames::find()->all(),'productnames_productname','productnames_productname'),
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Product'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'allowClear' => true
                    ],
                    //'productname' => $productname,
                    ]);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <?= DatePicker::widget([
                    'name' => 'Start Date',
                    'attribute' => 'from_date',
                    'value' => '2014-01-31',
                    'template' => '{addon}{input}',
                        'clientOptions' => [
                            'autoclose' => true,
                            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                        ]
                ]);?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <?= DatePicker::widget([
                    'name' => 'End Date',
                    'attribute' => 'to_date',
                    'value' => '2014-01-31',
                    'template' => '{addon}{input}',
                        'clientOptions' => [
                            'autoclose' => true,
                            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                        ]
                ]);?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1" >
                <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
                 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**2.Controller**

now inside your controller you can access parametes as follows

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $productname = Yii::$app->request->post('productnames_productname');
        $searchModel = new ProductionSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $productname);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: after implementing this, there's no error but not getting the desired output. The value is not filtering. I've added the output in the question.

Comment: Hi Nitin, I'm not getting the desired. output. Can you have a look?

Comment: Hey Tanmay, you need to debug it yourself, Its hard to guess the error, check what is the query generated using debug toolbar which is present at the footer